# using tc control command in bash script gives unexplainable results

Tags: bash, network-traffic, trafficshaping

I send frames in packets from a client to a server on the server I want to shape my traffic.
I use this script to control the traffic. First down to 80 kbit after 10 seconds down to 40 kbit. (I know this is ridiculously low, I usually use bigger values)

```
#!/bin/bash
datenrate=80
datenrate2=40
echo "setting datarate to ${datenrate}"
touch started.info
sudo tc qdisc del dev ens3 root
sudo tc qdisc add dev ens3 handle 1: root htb default 11
sudo tc class add dev ens3 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate ${datenrate}kbit
sudo tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate ${datenrate}kbit
echo "worked"
MSECONDS=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
STOPTIME=0
while : 
do
STOPTIME=$((($(date +%s%N)/1000000) - $MSECONDS))
    if [ $STOPTIME -ge 10000 ]
    then
        sudo tc qdisc del dev ens3 root
        sudo tc qdisc add dev ens3 handle 1: root htb default 11
        sudo tc class add dev ens3 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate ${datenrate2}kbit
        sudo tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate ${datenrate2}kbit
        touch calledthrottle.info
        break
    fi
done
echo "10 sec over - setting up a datarate drop to ${datenrate2} kbit"
while :
do
STOPTIME=$((($(date +%s%N)/1000000) - $MSECONDS))
    if [ $STOPTIME -ge 20000 ]
    then
        sudo tc qdisc del dev ens3 root
        echo "set to normal"
        break
    fi
done
touch ended.info
```

On my client I generate a logfile which I plot with GNUPlot and I both calculate the avg uploadspeed on server and on the client. In this case 2740 kbit/s. Am I not using the tc tool correctly?

Image of my results generated with GNUPlot:
[Upload speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThYj.png)

`tc qdisc show dev ens3`

gives me

> qdisc pfifo_fast 0: root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

which Im not able to delete with

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev ens3 root
```

Would be kind if someone could point me in the right direction and could explain why there is such a high upload rate, why there are frames coming through with a far higher throughput then shaped. Thank you.

---

Updated as adviced

---

Ok upload rate 80 kbit in tc gives me around 80*8 = 640 KiloBit/s. Still does not explain the fluctuation of the packet income